# Eclipse references files from other project after copying project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I took a project and copied it in eclipse, now when I run the maven command to compile it it's giving errors because there are missing variables.  The code that is being referenced is in the old project and I need to know how to make the build process recognize the code in the new project instead of the old project.

[image]

Here's what I get at the command prompt.

[image]

The project file that it should be referencing is the OpenExcel.java in the new project but instead it is referencing the file in the old project VegaAutomatisierungPart1.

[image]

I need to know how to make it reference the new project, I tried looking through all of the files in the project folder but I didn't see any that talked about referencing the old project so I'm not sure what to do.

Here is my pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>VegaAutomatisierungPart1</groupId>
  <artifactId>VegaAutomatisierungPart1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
           <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
           <version>1.10.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
             <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>
  <build>
   
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is the code it is referencing.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be compile the code from the new project (the paths in the error message contain `../AutomatisierteAnlaufsteuerung/..`). What seems to be wrong are the `groupId` and the `artifactId` that are defined in the `pom.xml` file of your copied project

Comment: Do you know what I should change?  I posted my pom.xml in the question.

Comment: As I have written in the first comment: you should change the `groupId` and the `artifactId` - in your POM these are on lines 5 and 6 (instead of `<groupId>VegaAutomatisierungPart1</groupId>` it should probably be `<groupId>AutomatisierteAnlaufsteuerung</groupId>`, for the `artifactId` something similar)

Comment: That changed the text but it's still returning the same variables on the same lines as in the old project and it's not using the new code in the new project.

Comment: The error message `/C:/Users/D171_o_QECJACK031/eclipse-workspace/AutomatisierteAnlaufsteuerung/src/OpenExcel.java:[50,67] cannot find symbol` clearly states that it tries to compile the file `OpenExcel.java` from the default package of the project `AutomatisierteAnlaufsteuerung`.

Comment: And the screenshot from eclipse shows that there are errors in the files in the collapsed package `(default package)` under your `src` folder. Maybe there are some old files from the old project that you should cleanup first?

Answer (score 0):

I see your old project is closed, try to write click on your old project and choose > `Open Project`